# Pass user input to web service

Tags: php, json

Hi need to pass some values to a web service. The code below is running fine. The only problem I have is that the values, in this case "3620" (postal code) and "600" (usage) should be entered by a user on a page and than pass to the webservice which return a result ($json). What is the best approach? A html form? I'd rather have it so the user has to fill in the two fields en clicks a "Go" button but that the results is shown on the same page. Anyone an idea how to make the two values user input?

```
          <?php 

      $service_url = 'http://test';
      $curl = curl_init($service_url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                                  'Content-Type: application/json',
                                                  'Connection: Keep-Alive'
                                                  ));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test:test");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           $curl_post_data = array(
                "postalcode" => 3620,
                "usage" => 600,
                );
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($curl_post_data));
      $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
      $json = json_decode($curl_response);
      curl_close($curl);

      var_dump($json);

    ?>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ on the client, and $_POST or $_GET in your code. jquery and other have fine easy ajax support or evt. a ajax post directly to the service with the new html5 cross domain ajax.

Comment: Don't you think sending `$curl_post_data` to the web service is the same as submitting a html form with fields named as 'postalcode' and 'usage' to that particular web service?

Comment: Yes you will need a form to do that. And you can pass any php variable to your CURL.